# Is Microsoft really updating Calculator each and every week?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, calculator

For at least 2-3 days each week, each time I open Start Menu it shows me this:

[image]

(from day to day the only difference is progress depicted by that white bar -- sometimes it shows about 70%)

Is this some weird Windows 10 bug or is Calculator really being updated so often?

Comment: This is usually an indication a Win 10 (UWP) 'app' is stuck doing an update. Slightly easy fix: create new user, confirm issue not there, move files to new user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculator is not updating each week (I look in Reliability History and this is a good way to know).

Calculator in Start on my Windows 10 systems looks fine.

[image: Calculator in Start]

Try the initial repairs for Windows 10:

(1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup .

(2) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .

(3) SFC /SCANNOW .

Restart and test .